# SonarQube 7.9.1 LTS is not starting up: Unable to create shared memory

Tags: sonarqube, illegalargumentexception

Following is the error: /opt/sonar/sonarqube-7.9.1/temp/sharedmemory (Too many open files in system)

I deleted the data/es6 directory and starting the SonarQube service, after some time the following error occurs and stop the process

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create shared memory : 
        at org.sonar.process.sharedmemoryfile.AllProcessesCommands.<init>(AllProcessesCommands.java:103)
        at org.sonar.process.sharedmemoryfile.DefaultProcessCommands.<init>(DefaultProcessCommands.java:34)
        at org.sonar.process.sharedmemoryfile.DefaultProcessCommands.secondary(DefaultProcessCommands.java:52)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isOperational(WebServer.java:69)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.getStatus(WebServer.java:61)
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.waitForStatus(ProcessEntryPoint.java:121)
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:104)
        at org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:81)
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:99)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/sonar/sonarqube-7.9.1/temp/sharedmemory (Too many open files in system)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:345)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
        at java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:214)
        at org.sonar.process.sharedmemoryfile.AllProcessesCommands.<init>(AllProcessesCommands.java:100)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 3):

As your log said, you can't create the shared memory, delete your shared memory file and restart the SonarQube service, SonarQube will create a new shared memory file for you.

Please make sure you backup your file before you delete it.